# Syntax error (from clause) in query expression in statement

Tags: c#, sql

```
string sqlStatement = "SELECT Orders.[ID], Orders.[Checkintime], Orders.[RoomPrice], Orders.[OrderNo], Particulars.FirstName, Particulars.LastName FROM Orders, where Checkintime between '" + dateOnly + "' and '" + endDateOnly + "', Particulars;";
```

I tried using this statement to select information from my database but this statement has syntax errors from the FROM clause

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the two tables (Orders and Particulars) are joined by some field that acts as a foreignkey. So you should have a OrderID field in the Particulars table that links every 'particular' to the respective Order.

If this is the case then your query should be something like this

```
string sqlStatement = @"SELECT Orders.[ID], Orders.[Checkintime], 
                        Orders.[RoomPrice], Orders.[OrderNo], 
                        Particulars.FirstName, Particulars.LastName 
                        FROM Orders INNER JOIN Particulars 
                        ON Orders.[ID] = Particulars.[OrderID]
                        where Checkintime between '" + dateOnly + 
                        "' and '" + endDateOnly + "'";
```

However this approach with string concatenation is prone to other kind of errors like parsing problems and Sql injection, better use a parameterized query

```
string sqlStatement = @"SELECT Orders.[ID], Orders.[Checkintime], 
                        Orders.[RoomPrice], Orders.[OrderNo], 
                        Particulars.FirstName, Particulars.LastName 
                        FROM Orders INNER JOIN Particulars 
                        ON Orders.[ID] = Particulars.[OrderID]
                        where Checkintime between @init AND @end";
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(.....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, cnn))
{
     cnn.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@init", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateOnly;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDateOnly;

     .... remainder of your code that reads back your data.....
}
```

Please note, the value supplied to the Parameter.Value should be a DateTime variable not a string....

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove that `,` here `Orders, where`
2. That `, Particulars;` doesn't makes sence as well probably you should use a join `... FROM Orders join Particulars ON Orders.ID = Particulars.ID` or what the ID-column is called
3. Depending on your Culture the DateTime could cause a problem when it's passed as a string value `'04/08/2015 21:52:39'`. e.g. in some cultures day and month are swapped.  You can do `dateOnly.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` or better use parameters and pass a DateTime object to avoids injection attacks additional

Comment: I removed the comma and it showed me this "Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'Checkintime between '04/08/2015 21:52:39' and '05/08/2015 00:00:00', Particulars'."}

Answer (score 0):

you need a join query:

```
string sqlStatement = "SELECT Orders.[ID], Orders.[Checkintime], Orders.[RoomPrice], Orders.[OrderNo], Particulars.FirstName, Particulars.LastName FROM Orders inner join Particulars  on Orders.CommonField=Particulars.CommonField
where Checkintime between '" + dateOnly + "' and '" + endDateOnly + "'";
```